# Programming with OpenOCD config file - how do I know my layout_init signal?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, jtag, ftdi, openocd

we designed a custom board that contains wifi module: EWB-STERLING,(453-00014R ) with STM32F412 chip.
I succeed in programming the module, but I noticed that it does not send a reset after each programming process like the DVK .

I look at the DVK of the LAIRD in schematic and see :

[image]

The USB_MICRO_RST controlled by the the FTDI with file cfg file: "CYW9WCD1VAL1.cfg" ,

this is the lines from the file:

ftdi_vid_pid 0x0a5c 0x43fa 0x04b4 0xf900

**ftdi_layout_init 0x0008 0x020b**

**ftdi_layout_signal nSRST -data 0x0080 -oe 0x0080**

**ftdi_layout_signal nTRST -data 0x0200 -oe 0x0200**

#ftdi_tdo_sample_edge falling

The highlighted lines indicate how the FTDI is masked, in which mode it will wake up(After some reading in OPENOCD GUIDE) and the behavior of MCU_RESET signal.

In my case my FTDI4232HL designed differently:

[image]

You can see that the RESET signal is connected to BDBUS3 (the name is written differently so I wrote it manually), how do I link the mask of the file I mentioned above(CYW9WCD1VAL1) and the RESET that needs to be done like they do in EVB?

*I tried to understand from the OPENOCD guide but without success, I don't understand the functionality of ftdi_layout_signal

*EDIT: Please note that im not using any level shifter/driver likewise in the DVK(U9) in the schematic.

In my board, the signal routed directly to MCU